# ORA-00984 column not allowed here in PL/SQL procedure

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, syntax-error

```
create or replace procedure pro_enroll(sname_in IN varchar, cname_in IN varchar)
as
sno STUDENT.snum%type;
begin
    SELECT snum INTO sno FROM STUDENT WHERE sname=sname_in;
    --dbms_output.put_line(sno || chr(9) || sname_in || chr(9) || cname_in);
    INSERT INTO ENROLLED(snum, cname) VALUES(sno, c_name_in);
end pro_enroll;
/

SELECT * FROM ENROLLED;

begin
pro_enroll('M.Lee', 'CS448');
pro_enroll('A.Smith', 'ENG320');
end;
/

SELECT * FROM ENROLLED;
```

Why am I getting "ORA-00984 column not allowed here"?
In ENROLLED:

```
CREATE TABLE ENROLLED
(
snum INTEGER NOT NULL,
cname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (snum, cname),
FOREIGN KEY (snum) REFERENCES STUDENT(snum),
FOREIGN KEY (cname) REFERENCES CLASS(cname) 
);
```

Answer (score 3):

You have used `c_name_in` name of argument in your `INSERT`, however, the actual name of the parameter of your procedure is `cname_in`, without the `_` sign between `c` and `name`, this works:

```
create or replace procedure pro_enroll(sname_in IN varchar, cname_in IN varchar)
as
sno STUDENT.snum%type;
begin
    SELECT snum INTO sno FROM STUDENT WHERE sname=sname_in;
    --dbms_output.put_line(sno || chr(9) || sname_in || chr(9) || cname_in);
    INSERT INTO ENROLLED(snum, cname) VALUES(sno, cname_in);
end pro_enroll;
/
```